# Using cookies on jQuery "toggleClass"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I've been trying to search for a way to use cookies to save the change done by toggle on my website, but i can't get my head around cookies. Please help me i'm just new at jQuery and cookies.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#switch").click(function(){
     $("body").toggleClass("main");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please show what you tried so we can clear up your confusion.

Comment: I made my code simpler, i want the cookies to remember the change made by toggleclass. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/dYk4T/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie to manage your cookies. Very simple and effective. You'll just have to modify your script :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#switch").click(function(){
    $("body").toggleClass("main");
    $.cookie('your_cookie_name', 'your_cookie_value');
  });
});
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Load the jQuery cookie plugin, as referenced in Flo's answer. Then you can save the state with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#switch").click(function(){
        $("body").toggleClass("main");
        $.cookie("main", $("body").hasClass("main"));
    });
});
```

You can later get the value of the cookie with:

```
var main_set = $.cookie("main");
```

Comment: Where do I put the var main_set = $.cookie("main");?

Comment: In whatever code wants to use the cookie. You set it for a reason, didn't you?